# Subquery results more than one values

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two tables:

**table_people**

- col_name
- col_sex

**table_gender**

- col_male
- col_female

Suppose the `table_people` consist three rows, ***(a,'M'),(b,'M'),(c,'F')***.

Now I need a query(subquery) to insert this first table value in second table as:
***(a,c),(b,'')***.

If it is possible in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You table structure is bad.

My suggestion is to drop `table_gender` because it doesn't make sense at all. You already have a list of person with gender on table `table_people`.

You can generate a `VIEW`, if you want to list the gender separately.

```
CREATE VIEW MaleList
AS
SELECT col_name
FROM   table_people
WHERE  col_sex = 'M'
```

and another view for list of females only.

```
CREATE VIEW FemaleList
AS
SELECT col_name
FROM   table_people
WHERE  col_sex = 'F'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the table structure is bad. I dont see a point of saving M or F in another table when you col_sex in your table_people. Still if you want to do it, first you have to specify a foreign key connecting the two tables.